# How can I reset items in UITableView after a move or deletion - to keep my alternate row colors?

Tags: swift, xcode12

My program successfully alternates the colors between odd and even rows in UITableView. However, after I delete or move an item, the alternation is lost. How can I reset or refresh the view (and remain on the same items... not jump to row 0).

```
import UIKit

class ItemsViewController: UITableViewController {
    
    var itemStore: ItemStore!
    
    @IBAction func addNewItem(_ sender: UIButton){

        let newItem = itemStore.createItem()

        if let index = itemStore.allItems.firstIndex(of: newItem) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
            
            //inset this new row into the table
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
    
    @IBAction func toggleEditingMode(_ sender: UIButton){
        if isEditing {
            sender.setTitle("Edit", for: .normal)
            setEditing(false, animated: true)
        } else {
            sender.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
            setEditing(true, animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemStore.allItems.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UITableViewCell", for: indexPath)
        let item = itemStore.allItems[indexPath.row]
   
        cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "$\(item.valueInDollars)"

        // ****** THIS WHERE I DESIGNATE THE COLOR FOR EACH ROW
        if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
            print(indexPath.row)
        } else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        }

        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingSytle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         if editingSytle == .delete {
             let item = itemStore.allItems[indexPath.row]
             itemStore.removeItem(item)
             tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
         }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        itemStore.moveItem(from: sourceIndexPath.row, to: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }
}
```

Comment: Reload the table guy.

Comment: Thanks. reloadData() worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Modifications to your `itemsStore` should reload the view:

```
var itemsStore: ItemStore! {
   didSet {
       tableView.reloadData()
   }
}
```

That will make sure that `cellForRowAt` is called again and the colors will update.